# WordPress admin-ajax.php file is not loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i try to make a live ajax search.

I use this code in my functions.php :

```
function add_js_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-wpm', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/script-wpm.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

    wp_localize_script('script-wpm', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js_scripts');
```

My JS file is loaded, but can't see admin-ajax.php in the dev console of google chrome :

[image: You can see my screenshot here]

I don't know why it's not loading. Do you have an idea please? Thank you

Comment: Did `script-wpm.js` get loaded into the page? You can see this in page source. My gut says that if that doesn't load (for example, if your path is incorrect -- which can be kind of tricky), that the call to localize won't do anything.

Comment: Hello, yes script-wpm.js is loaded in the page. I can see it in page source

Comment: Ahh... looks like wp_localize_scripts wants an array for the third parameter. admin_url() returns a string. I'd try array( admin_url(...) )

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script